# Does typeid(T) get evaluated at run time or compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, rtti

I cannot find the answer to this seemingly simple question anywhere.

Does the following C++ function use RTTI?  It certainly doesn't have to, but I was wondering if there is a guarantee that typeid will be determined at compile time.

```
template <typename T>
const char *getName()
{
   return typeid(T).name();   // Resolved at compile time?
}
```

Comment: I think it is evaluated at runtime. as type T is not know at compile time

Comment: What object would it use RTTI on?

Comment: @someone_smiley: How would the compiler generate a correct specialization if it didn't know what `T` was?

Comment: The "Notes" section on cpp reference says (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid): "When applied to an expression of polymorphic type, evaluation of a typeid expression may involve runtime overhead (a virtual table lookup), otherwise typeid expression is resolved at compile time."

Comment: I imagine it could be evaluated at compile-time by the compiler in the case of `typeid(T)` or `typeid(x)` where the static type of `x` is a concrete class, but it is never a *constant-expression*.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: T has to be known at compile time, otherwise the program can't compile.

Comment: @Watusimoto: but `T` is a type, not an object. (If you were responding to my first comment.)

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Yes; the compiler knows all the classes that getName() can be called with, and it "detemplatifies" the code and creates a getName() function for each type.  It does not do this dynamically at run time. (And typeid works on types as well as objects.)

Comment: @piwi go and write an answer.

Comment: @Watusimoto: If you know that then I don't understand what question you are asking.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: The question states that the typeid can be determined at compile time, but I was asking if it actually was guaranteed to do so because all the documentation I have seen on the matter is vague on this point.  It focuses instead on the need to use RTTI to determine type of a pointer at runtime, leaving my question unanswered.  My immediate motivation was that one of my colleagues thought I was incurring additional overhead with a function like this, and I was having a hard time disproving him.

Comment: Why not scrub the reference to RTTI entirely from the question, it's just causing confusion. It's not relevant to you. There is no object involved in your use of `typeid` so there can be no RTTI. Instead just ask if "typeid( typeid )" is resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `typeid` is applied to a type rather than an object, there *is* no runtime type information, so that overhead won't be a problem.

On the other hand: as far as I can see, the standard makes no requirements regarding when the value will be determined, so there's no guarantee that there's *no* runtime overhead.

---

Edit:
Of course, the fact that there's (possibly) no guarantee doesn't mean that it's not a reasonable assumption.
I can't imagine that anyone would write a compiler that *didn't* evaluate `typeid(T)` at compile time.

Answer (score 7):

As I mentioned in a comment, the "Notes" section regarding `typeid()` on [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) says:

> When applied to an expression of polymorphic type, evaluation of a typeid expression may involve runtime overhead (a virtual table lookup), otherwise typeid expression is resolved at compile time.

Comment: In this instance `T` is a type, not an expression.

Comment: @molbdnilo So the expression `typeid(T)` is resolved at compile time.  (The compiler may still generate the call to `std::type_info::name` on  it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Shame on me for not reading the whole sentence... I still can't find any reference to compile-time resolution in The Standard, though.

Comment: @molbdnilo I thought that that was what he was quoting.  You're right; the standard doesn't make any guarantee (although it's hard to see how it could be otherwise when you use `typeid` with a type name).  Still, it's an error in his source.